# What should I do with a shallow closet?

Tags: closet

My guest bedroom has an extra shallow closet (15 inches deep).  This is too narrow for a hanger, so clothes hung on the rod end up being angled, rubbing against the back wall and the door, etc.

What can I do with this thing?  It needs to remain a closet, but I need an alternate method to hang clothes.  I've thought about trying to rotate the rod.  Perhaps I could hang two rods somehow so they go from front-to-back rather than from side-to-side?  But, how could I support the door-side end?  Well, I could hang it from the shelf somehow.  The shelf is fairly sturdy.  Any ideas on how to mount such a rod?  Or other ideas on how to refurb the closet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an antique chifforobe that is only 16" deep. I purchased 'petite' or kids hangers from Amazon. they are 14" wide and big enough to hold most adult clothing. Bonus, they are very thin and flocked so that your clothes won't slip off.

Answer (score 1):

I had a closet once that wasn't particularly shallow, but it did have 3 closet bars mounted front-to-back, and I found the multiple bars very convenient for organizing my clothes.

The left and right bar ran between the front and back walls (the closet had a swinging door in the middle, not a full-width sliding door), and the middle bar's front end was suspended from the shelf above by a triangular wooden bracket (perpendicular to the bar). The middle bar was half the depth of the closet, so you could walk in and reach the side bars easily. Note that the shelf was supported by wooden rails fastened to the wall on three sides, not just shelf brackets on the back wall; the whole system felt quite solid.

I think a design like that would work very well for the closet you describe, and all of the parts were wood, so they could easily be made to fit.

If you are interested then I could make a drawing of the design as I remember it, or perhaps even arrange for a photograph.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that instantly came to mind was this:
[image]

I bought one from Goodwill years ago, the top on mine swivels but then you would have to take it out or fight it to get to the other side.

I also found this:

[image: Picture 1]

This model specifically seems to be for over the door mounting but I bet you find a flush mount one or install a 2x4 in the back of the closest as a rail to support them.

Image Sources:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/2-New-Folding-Multi-function-Magic-Hangers-Clothes-Rack-/190622930311?_trksid=p3284.m263&_trkparms=algo%3DSIC%26its%3DI%26itu%3DUCI%252BIA%252BUA%252BIEW%252BFICS%252BUFI%26otn%3D21%26pmod%3D180899714769%26ps%3D54

http://www.grainger.com/Grainger/HONEYCANDO-OvertheDoor-Folding-Hanger-Holder-15V409

Answer (score 0):

Why not use slide out closet bars such as [this one](http://www.thehardwarehut.com/catalog-product.php?p_ref=37206)
[image: slide out bar]

It is mounted under the shelf.

Answer (score -1):

What about just installing some more shelves?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://diy.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://diy.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Steven I think this qualifies as an answer given the end of the question: “Or other ideas on how to refurb the closet?”

Comment: While this technically *may* be an answer, in general answering a question with a question is not proper etiquette.  Consider editing your answer to provide a bit more detail.